# SQL Query by date less than does not select all data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `logging_data` with structure like this:

```
+----+---------------------+---------+-----------+---------+--------+
| id |        date         | user_id | id_device | room_id | device |
+----+---------------------+---------+-----------+---------+--------+
| 28 | 2020-02-12 13:52:16 |       1 |         2 |       1 |        |
| 27 | 2020-02-11 13:52:16 |       0 |         2 |       1 |        |
| 26 | 2020-02-10 13:52:16 |       0 |         2 |       1 |        |
| 25 | 2020-02-09 13:52:16 |       1 |         2 |       1 |        |
+----+---------------------+---------+-----------+---------+--------+
```

I'm trying to

```
SELECT * FROM `logging_data` WHERE `date` < "2020-02-12 00:00:00"
```

I want to get all data, but it return only data with `user_id = 0`, 
like this:

```
+----+---------------------+---------+-----------+---------+--------+
| id |        date         | user_id | id_device | room_id | device |
+----+---------------------+---------+-----------+---------+--------+
| 27 | 2020-02-11 13:52:16 |       0 |         2 |       1 |        |
| 26 | 2020-02-10 13:52:16 |       0 |         2 |       1 |        |
+----+---------------------+---------+-----------+---------+--------+
```

Can somebody explain why, what am I doing wrong? how can I get all data including `user_id = 1`?

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Your query seems correct, try to `ORDER BY user_id DESC`

Comment: 1) Use single quote char `'` instead of doublequote `"` for literals wrapping. 2) The query MUST select all users, not only `user_id = 0`, try to add `ORDER BY user_id = 0` for the records with values over zero to be first.

Comment: What datatype is date?

Comment: Thank you all, my bad that I edit the data so the date is update itself then I got that answer.